# C queue incorrectly storing values

Tags: c, queue

I am trying to set up a queue in C but when something new is queued it ends up duplicating the head value each time instead of storing that new item.

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct packet_queue {
  struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
  unsigned char *packet;
  struct packet_queue *next;
};
struct packet_queue *head = NULL;
struct packet_queue *tail = NULL;

int run = 0;
int packets = 0;
int v;


void enqueue(struct packet_queue *pq) {
  if (head == NULL) {
    head = pq;
  }
  else {
    struct packet_queue *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = pq;
  }
  packets++;
}


void printqueue() {
  struct packet_queue * current = head;
  int i = 50;
  while (i > 0 && current != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", current->header->len);
    current = current->next;
    i--;
  }
}

void dispatch(struct pcap_pkthdr *header,
              const unsigned char *packet,
              int verbose) {
  v = verbose;
  int i;

  struct packet_queue *next_packet = (struct packet_queue *) malloc(sizeof(struct packet_queue));
  next_packet->header = (struct pcap_pkthdr *) header;
  next_packet->packet = (unsigned char * ) packet;
  next_packet->next = NULL;
  enqueue(next_packet);
}
```

When printing the queue using `printqueue()` it prints the same value each time (the head value) suggesting the head is duplicated through the queue.

EDIT: Did a bit more testing and realised the entire queue is set to whatever the last-added item is.

```
struct pcap_pkthdr header;
  const unsigned char *packet;

  //initialise dynamic array
  dynarray_init(&syn_adds, 5);

  while (1) {
    // Capture a  packet
    packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, &header);
    if (packet == NULL) {
      // pcap_next can return null if no packet is seen within a timeout
      if (verbose) {
        printf("No packet received. %s\n", pcap_geterr(pcap_handle));
      }
    } else {
      // Optional: dump raw data to terminal
      if (verbose) {
         //dump(packet, header.len);
      }
      // Dispatch packet for processing
      dispatch(&header, packet, verbose);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not related to the problem at hand, but casting a `const unsigned char *` to an `unsigned char *` is not a good idea.

Comment: What's calling `dispatch`? Where are `header` and `packet` being allocated?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I've added const to the struct thanks! I've edited the question to add where dispatch is called

Comment: "The struct  pcap_pkthdr  and
       the  packet  data  are  not  to be freed by the caller, and are not guaranteed to be valid
       after the next call to pcap_next_ex(), pcap_next(), pcap_loop(),  or  pcap_dispatch();  if
       the code needs them to remain valid, it must make a copy of them." http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man3/pcap_next_ex.3pcap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queue is fine. The problem is that you call `dispatch` with the same pointers. You keep passing the address of the same `struct pcap_pkthdr header;` as `header`, and the manual for `pcap_next` says this:

> pcap_next() reads the next packet (by calling pcap_dispatch() with a cnt of 1) and returns a u_char pointer to the data in that packet. The packet data is not to be freed by the caller, and is not guaranteed to be valid after the next call to pcap_next_ex(), pcap_next(), pcap_loop(), or pcap_dispatch(); if the code needs it to remain valid, it must make a copy of it. The pcap_pkthdr structure pointed to by h is filled in with the appropriate values for the packet.

For both of them, the solution is the same: you need to `malloc` fresh pointers for each call to `dispatch`, and copy the data into them.

Comment: Sorry still a bit confused. Would this be in the second code snippet before dispatch is called? or would I have to make a copy inside the dispatch function?

Comment: @finn_101 It doesn't matter where you do it, just that you do.

Comment: Makes sense. What would be the best way to copy a const unsigned char * ?

Comment: @finn_101 If it's a NUL-terminated string, then `strdup`. If it's just an array of bytes, then `malloc` followed by `memcpy`.

Comment: How do I retrieve the size of the data? I am trying `strlen(packet)` but it comes out as 1 or 2 each time which is obviously not correct